# Get data function in Dexie is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

My function is simple. Create table, bulk put data and retriew object based on index.

```
const db = new Dexie('data');
const dataToInsert = [{id: "aaaa", name: "bbb"}]

function data() {
var exists = await Dexie.exists("data");
  if (!exists) {
    await db.version(1).stores({
      data: 'id,name'
    });
    await db.geo.bulkPut(dataToInsert);
  }
  var record = await db.geo.get("aaaa");
}
```

I can see everything is inserted. But GET function is returning:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')`

Even db.geo is undefined... any idea why?

Comment: have you resolv this problem? i have the same isuue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you haven't define `geo` table schema so [`Dexie`](https://dexie.org/) don't know about it.

If you meant `data` schema instead of `geo` schema then to fix just change `data` to `geo` in schema definition

```
const db = new Dexie('data');
const dataToInsert = [{id: "aaaa", name: "bbb"}]

function data() {
  var exists = await Dexie.exists("data");
  if (!exists) {
    await db.version(1).stores({
      data: 'id,name'
    });
    await db.data.bulkPut(dataToInsert);
  }
  var record = await db.data.get("aaaa");
}
```

Or add missing `geo` schema.